# NativeScript items of custom FAB(floating action button) cannot be tapped

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, floating-action-button

[PlayGround Example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=AIQOcR&v=5)

How to make the `<FabItem>` tapped instead of the background `<ListView>`
on the example above?

[image: FabItem]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are not clickable as it's not actually accessible to user.

It's visible just because all of it's parent layouts are transparent. If you apply background color to `fabItemPosition` you will notice that it actually occupies only the space that is required only for the fab button not for fab items. Fab items should be within bounds of parent layout in order to be accessible to user.

And in my opinion, there are too many nested layouts which you could restructure. Refer [nslayouts](https://www.nslayouts.com/) to learn more about layouts.